# Data Flow output to Azure SQL Database contains only NULL data on Azure Data Factory

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I'm testing the data flow on my Azure Data Factory. I created Data Flow with the following details:
Source dataset linked service - from CSV files dataset from Blob storage
Sink linked service - Azure SQL database with pre-created table
My CSV files are quite simple as they contain only 2 columns (PARENT, CHILD). So, my table in SQL DB also have only 2 columns.

[image: CSVdataset]

For the sink setting of my data flow, I have allowed insert data and leaving other options as default.

[image: SinkAllowInsert]

I have also mapped the 2 columns for input and output columns as per screenshot.

[image: mapColumns]

[image: mapColumns2]

The pipeline with data flow ran successfully when I checked the result, I could see thqat 5732 rows were processed. Is this the correct way to check? As this is the first time I try this functionality in Azure Data Factory.

[image: rowProceesed]

But, when I click on **Data preview** tab, they are all NULL value.

[image: allNULLvalues]

And; when I checked my Azure SQL DB in the table where I tried to insert the data from CSV files from Blob storage with selecting top 1000 rows from this table, I don't see any data.

[image: SQLnoData]

Could you please let me know what I configured incorrectly on my Data Flow? Thank you very much in advance.

Here is the screenshot of ADF data flow source data, it does see the data on the right side as they are not NULL, but on the left side are all NULLs. I imagine that the right side are the data from the CSV from the source on the blob right? And the left side is the sink destination as the table is empty for now?

[image: ADFsourceData]

And here is the screenshot for the sink inspect input, I think this is correct as it reads the 2 columns correctly (Parent, Child), is it?

[image: ADFsinkDataInspect]

After adding Map drifted, to map "Parent" => "parent" and "Child" => "child"

[image: mapDrift0]

I get this error message after running the pipeline.

[image: mapdrift1]

When checking on sink data preview, I get this error message. It seems like there is incorrect mapping?

[image: mapdrifted1]

I rename the MapDrifted1 expression to "toString(byName('Parent1))" and Child1 as suggested.

[image: MapDrifted1]

The data flow executed successfully, however I still get NULL data in the sink SQL table.

[image: NULLdata1]

[image: NULLdata2]

Answer (score 1):

Can you copy/paste the script behind your data flow design graph? Go to the ADF UI, open the data flow, then click the Script button on top right.

In your Source transformation, click on Data Preview to see the data. Make sure you are seeing your data, not NULLs. Also, look at the Inspect on the *INPUT* for your Sink, to see if ADF is reading additional columns.

Comment: Hello @Mark Kromer, thank you very much again for your help. Here is the data flow script:

source(output(
  Parent as string,
  Child as string
 ),
 allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: false,
 ignoreNoFilesFound: false) ~> source1
source1 sink(input(
  PARENT as string,
  CHILD as string
 ),
 allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: true,
 deletable:false,
 insertable:true,
 updateable:false,
 upsertable:false,
 format: 'table',
 mapColumn(
  PARENT = Parent,
  CHILD = Child
 )) ~> sinkAzureSQLserver

Comment: I don't know how to add screenshots in the comment, therefore I added the new screenshots in my question above.

Comment: It looks like your source file column names are actually all lowercase. Notice in your new screenshot that they are listed as "drifted" columns because your dataset schema defines Parent, Child ... but your file is lowercase column names. Click that "Map Drifted" button on that data preview screen and then you can map the lowercase columns in your sink.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this.

Comment: Hello @Mark Kromer Sorry to bother you again. I followed your instruction to add Map Drifted between Source and Sink. Please, see new screenshots above. I did mapped "Parent" to "parent" and "Child" to "child" but I still get this error message in the screenshot above.

Comment: Can you try renaming the columns in MapDrifted1 to something that differentiates from "parent" and "child" like "Parent1" and "Child1" ?

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. When you said renaming the columns in MapDrifted1, do you mean to rename it here in the expression? For example, toString(byName('Parent1)), please see screenshot above?
I tried this and the data flow ran successfully. However, when I check data preview after, it seems like I still get NULL data in the output SQL table. Please see additional screenshot above. What do you think I can do further to solve this issue? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: paste the script again, i'll take a look

Comment: Thank you very much @Mark Kromer, here is the script:

Comment: source(output(
  Parent as string,
  Child as string
 ),
 allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: false,
 ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
 wildcardPaths:['raw/CSV_DimenH']) ~> source1
source1 derive(parent = toString(byName('Parent1')),
  child = toString(byName('Child1'))) ~> MapDrifted1
MapDrifted1 sink(input(
  PARENT as string,
  CHILD as string
 ),
 allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: true,
 deletable:false,
 insertable:true,
 updateable:false,
 upsertable:false,
 format: 'table',
 mapColumn(
  PARENT = Parent,
  CHILD = Child
 )) ~> sinkAzureSQLserver

Comment: In the MapDrifted1 derived column, change "parent =" to "parent1 =" and "child =" to "child1 =" and then put the byName() back to the name of the incoming columns you are mapping.

Comment: Hello @Mark Kromer, I changed my script like this below

Comment: source(output(
  Parent as string,
  Child as string
 ),
 allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: false,
 ignoreNoFilesFound: false,
 wildcardPaths:['raw/CSV_DimenH']) ~> source1
source1 derive(parent1 = toString(byName('Parent')),
  child1 = toString(byName('Child'))) ~> MapDrifted1
MapDrifted1 sink(input(
  PARENT as string,
  CHILD as string
 ),
 allowSchemaDrift: true,
 validateSchema: true,
 deletable:false,
 insertable:true,
 updateable:false,
 upsertable:false,
 format: 'table',
 mapColumn(
  PARENT = Parent,
  CHILD = Child
 )) ~> sinkAzureSQLserver

Comment: Is this correct like you suggested? In the original CSV file, the columns are "Parent" and "Child". However, after running the pipeline, I still get all NULL in the SQL table output. Same result as previous. May be I should go ahead and modify my column names in my SQL DB table to be exactly same as the source from CSV?